# Finding number of days sice last change of date value given a condition

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, vba

In my first column A, I have dates going down since 2015 to present date. A2 across, the column headings or names of 50 suppliers. I am keen to know the number of days since the last change in Prices. The Process would be for me to go up from current date for each supplier until I see a significant difference >£x, and than go across to see the date and subtract this from current date to get the number of days since last change.

I can use index and match to find the price for a given supplier given current date, but I am not aware of function that allows you to find the most ecent number of days since the price changed for supplier. As I am keen to make this dynamic.

Example

```
  Date      A   B   C   D   E    
25/11/2016  0,  0   0   0   0   
26/11/2016  0,  50  0   30  0  
27/11/2016  0,  0   0   0   0  
28/11/2016  0,  0   0   0   0  
29/11/2016  40, 10  0   50  0  
30/11/2016  0,  0   30  0   0  
01/12/2016  0,  0   0   0   30  
02/12/2016  10, 0   0   0   0  
03/12/2016  0,  0   10  0   0  
04/12/2016  0,  10  0   10  10  
05/12/2016  0,  0   0   0   0  
06/12/2016  0,  0   0   0   0  
07/12/2016  10, 0   0   0   0  
08/12/2016  0,  0   20  0   0  
09/12/2016  0,  0   0   0   10  
10/12/2016  0,  0   0   0   0
```

Most recent No of days since chge
3 days  6 days  2 days  6 days  one day

I have added to show the first column using comma, but I am assuming you get my gist, signed up to Github. and do not know how to upload a spreadsheet

I am looking for the most RECENT

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you, depending on your definition of "significant" increase:

[image]

Array formula so use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to apply to the cell. You can then fill to the right.

Assumes no gaps in your price data.

If you want to determine based on % change then try variations using `(B3:B11/B2:B10)` in place of subtraction.

Comment: Hi Tim, would this formula equate to the following or do the following, as the values I have are difference for each supplier in prices, so typically some of these suppliers would change their prices on a daily basis and some would not, those that do not, e.g. this would be a 0, would this formula, go up from the most current date and find a value with a defined difference x, and than find the corresponding date to subtract from current to work out the number of days since the most recent change.

Comment: Yes -  try it out

Comment: i have 687 date rows, and its giving me value error.

Comment: I don't have your data - unless you can share it I'm not going to be able to do much here

Comment: I will create a sample and send you the link via github

Comment: I'm not seeing why my formula wouldn't work with that data.  If you can share a sample file (use Box, Dropbox, Google drive, etc etc) with actual data then that would help

Answer (score 0):

This formula is simply another approach :NOW()-INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MAX(IFERROR(IF(B$2:B$12-B$1:B$11>0,ROW(B$1:B$12)),0))) .

Comment: @user3287522 : Mine is an array formula as well.